# Combine checking for a valid URL and extracting file extension

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I am checking if a string is a valid URL, and then use another regex to get the file extension inside the URL.

This is the code I am using:

```
public string GetUrlFileName(string url) {

        string fileExtension = string.Empty;

        **Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.(?:jpg|gif|png|pdf))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?");**

        Match match = regex.Match(url.ToLower());

        if(match.Success) {

            **Regex regexEnetnsion = new Regex(@"([\w]{2,4})(\?|$)");**

            Match GetExtension = regexEnetnsion.Match(url);

            if(GetExtension.Success) {

                fileExtension = GetExtension.Value;
            }
        }
        return fileExtension;
    }
```

However, I'd like to combine these regular expressions to use just one.

Comment: You’re already matching `(?:jpg|gif|png|pdf)`; just take out the `?:` to make it capturing, then get the appropriate group’s value from `match.Groups`.

Comment: I suppose `preg_match` has got nothing to do with the question, I removed it from the tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [capturing group](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) instead of a non-capturing:

> Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, parentheses
>   also create a numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the
>   string matched by the part of the regular expression inside the
>   parentheses.

Thus, you can just remove `?:`:

```
(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.(jpg|gif|png|pdf))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?
                                          ^
```

Group 4 will contain your extension.

C#:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\.(jpg|gif|png|pdf))(?:\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?");
Match match = regex.Match(url.ToLower());
if(match.Success) {
    string ext = match.Groups[4].Value;
 ...
}
```

See [RegexStorm demo, see *Table* tab](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3F%3A(%5B%5E%3A%2F%3F%23%5D%2B)%3A)%3F(%3F%3A%2F%2F(%5B%5E%2F%3F%23%5D*))%3F(%5B%5E%3F%23%5D*%5C.(jpg%7Cgif%7Cpng%7Cpdf))(%3F%3A%5C%3F(%5B%5E%23%5D*))%3F(%3F%3A%23(.*))%3F&i=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2Fpic.gif)

Comment: Glad it helped. I'd encourage you to read the information on capturing groups on Regular-expressions.info. It will take just about 5 minutes of your time, but you will get a feel of what you can do with capturing groups in regex.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, if an answer proves useful, you can also upvote it by clicking the up arrow beside the answer. Now, you have this privilege after gaining +15 rep points.